# Count file rows in google bucket with Java

Tags: java, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

Is it possible to count rows in Google bucket blob without downloading it?
I am trying to read `csv` files from Google bucket and I need a way to count their rows without downloading them. Is it possible with the API that google provides?

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. Google Cloud Storage stores objects with the objective of reliability and availability. Google Cloud Storage does not provide processing power for analyzing the the contents of storage objects.

You will need to read the object in order to count the rows. The most efficient method would be to use a computing instance in the cloud to maximize bandwidth performance.

Google Cloud offers a number of storage services. Some of these provide processing power as part of the service. If your csv files are large, BigQuery would be an example that could analyze billions of rows in just seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following to count the lines of an object:

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob.BlobSourceOption;

public class CountObjectLines {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of("your-bucket", "your-file.csv"));
    //This will get the content of the object
    byte[] content = blob.getContent(BlobSourceOption.generationMatch());
    String csvContent= new String(content);
    //This will count the lines of the file
    String[] lines = csvContent.split("\r\n");
    System.out.println(lines.length);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that, the files are too big and i do not want to load them in memory. That is why i was looking for a way to count lines in the cloud :)

Comment: For this, you could try using BigQuery to query Cloud Storage data using [permanent external tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#permanent-tables) or [temporary tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#temporary-tables) with your Cloud Storage CSV files.